# Assigning object instances to ModelFields (and their magical journey to the database)?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm reading through the '[Creating a custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#what-does-a-field-class-do)' and I'm having trouble undestanding the journey an object instance takes to the DB. It mentions:

> > > It's important to realize that a Django field class is not what is stored in your model attributes. **The model attributes contain normal Python objects**. The field classes you define in a model are actually stored in the Meta class when the model class is created (the precise details of how this is done are unimportant here).

I understand that in writing a custom field, I am writing the glue code between a normal python object, and how it is saved to the database. [It goes on to talk about](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-python-objects-to-query-values) `get_prep_value` and that:

> > > The value parameter **is the current value of the model's attribute** (a field has no reference to its containing model, so it cannot retrieve the value itself)

As I understand, this is to say that `value` is the actual instance of whatever object you are trying to represent? i.e. (continuing the example) when I write:

```
myhand = Hand('Ah', '9s', '8c', '2d')
my_model.custom_hand_field = myhand
```

my `get_prep_value` method is called with `myhand` as the value?

If so, is a reference to `myhand` actually stored somewhere within the Field class, or is the field simply converting between the Hand and database value on the fly?

Furthermore, how does it get from the assignment of the hand to the model attribute in the code above to actually being stored in the DB via `get_prep_value' (whether or not a reference is stored in the Field class)?

---

**tl;dr** what magic is happening between an assignment of an instance to a model attribute and it reaching the DB, and how it `get_prep_value` involved?